# Understanding results of Toblers Cost Path in ArcGIS Spatial Analyst?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, spatial-analyst, cost-path

I'm using ESRI's Path Distance Analysis based on Toblers hiking function to estimate the walking time from an archaeological site to establish it's context.  Each color represents an hour of walking time, the red line is river which I made 100 meters wide and re-classed to NoData.  I think the first four hours of walking make a lot of sense.

But what is going on with when the model hits the coast line?

Especially with the middle blue value (the 7th hour of travel) - Tobler's estimates travel at roughly 5km per hour optimal speed but along the coast it is estimating travel at 16km an hour.

Is this edge distortion?

[image: Toblers attempt]

Comment: Check your table and units. And no travel possible over the river based on your scenario

Comment: The river can be crossed at the four locations where there is archaeological or historical records of bridges.  All of them are nearby the location of the site.  They are represented in the raster as a break of a few pixels in the river NoData line.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that you did something wrong when preparing the DEM and SLOPE rasters for the analysis. It seems that the "presence" of the river is actually disregarded by the analysis, so ArcMAP is not "realizing" that the river is set as NoData. Therefore, I am wondering if, once you buffered the river and reclassified it as NoData, you actually "subtracted" it from the DEM and related SLOPE rasters. In order to do that you may want to add the reclassified river raster to the DEM and SLOPE rasters via RASTER CALCULATOR. The rationale being that, in Map Algebra, data+NoData=NoData. That would allow the river to show up as NoData in the DEM and SLOPE rasters that you use to implement Tobler's hiking function in Path Distance.

Comment: I should have provided more details in my initial question.  I have a few breaks in the river - where there are bridges (or were bridges) contemporary with the archaeological site.  That looks as though it is working properly.  Along the coast though it seems as if there is are impossible walking speeds (circa 15km per hour).

Comment: Sorry but I do not get your point. By "coast" do you mean the left-most part of your raster? If that holds true, what I see is areas with darker colours, relative to the core zone. My best guess would be that those colours indicate values smaller than your core zone. But, not knowing the colour ramp you used, that remains just my impression. Secondly, at the best of my knowledge, in archaeology what it is used is the inverse of the Tobler's function, that is the function solved for time. So, in my experience, the countours indicate walking time-zones (isochrones).

Comment: If my latter comment holds true, your raster could be read off as indicating that the outermost blueish zones can be reached with a longer (time-wise) walk. I am wondering what procedure did you use to get that raster.

Comment: The coastline is the far left - I should have included the shapefile for the coastline in my clip.  That was an oversight on my part.  So the dot at the center is the archaeological site (it is just outside Rome) the river is the Tiber - you intuited correctly that the far left was the coast.  I was informed by [this lab](http://www.mapaspects.org/courses/gis-and-anthropology/weekly-class-exercises/week-9-anisotropic-cost-surfaces-and-least-cost-).

Comment: continued...The darkest blue would be about 9 hours travel on foot based on tobler's which suggests around 5kmph max on level ground.  According to virtually all pedestrian mobility scholarship is the average comfortable walking speed (it does vary according to many factors but standard is 5km).  I think I identified the problem - along the coast most of the elevation was zero or even a negative elevation value.  I think it was resulting in a zero cost to travel in some areas.  I  converted the water from 0 to ND, and added 4 meters in elevation and had much more reasonable results.

Comment: I really appreciate your response and consideration of my problem - I'm new to using StackExchange, please excuse any breach of proper board etiquette.

Comment: No problem, we are here to learn! I know the tutorial you were referring to. If you implemented the procedure properly, you should get a raster representing the walking time to move across the landscape. That's why I still do not get how you get the value of 15kmh (which is speed NOT time) from your raster. Moreover, from Tobler's function, it would be impossible to get a value larger than about 6 kmh,which is the maximum speed predicted by Tobler and that can be achieved on a gentle downslope. So, if you are getting 15 kmh anywhere from your raster, there's something wrong.

Comment: So, in summary, I see two issue (well, let's say two things that are not clear to me): 1) why you speak about speed when the way Tobler's function is implemented in that website is about time?; 2) why do you get that impossible (by Tobler funtion's standards) value of 15 KmH)?

Comment: The results of the lab - returns results in hours - which is how I color coded my response.  Then using the measuring tool I measured the maximum width of the bands the light blue and dark blue bands both were around 15km (give or take a KM) at their widest points. 

In other news I've found more problems with the MapAspect Lab - or how ArcGIS responds to it -  The Tobleraway.txt goes really wonky when imported - it drops most of Tobler's values.

I'm going to post a new question about it soon if you are still interested.

Comment: You should consider that by measuring the "width" of the area you are actually calculating a planar distance (as the crow flies), while Path Distance mapping uses the true (i.e., topographic) distance. This is clarified in the Path Distance help webpage. Therefore I belive that the way you devised that figure is not totally correct (i.e., is not consistent with what PathDistance does behind the scenes). Secondly, I do not totally follow what you said about the vertical factor. You should make yourself sure that there is no bug in the PathDistance tool in arcgis 10.2.

Comment: I seem to recall that I have read somewhere in the web that ESRI introduced a bug in the Path Distance tool somewhere along the development between 10.1 and following releases. The bug was fixed in the Pro Version. I use ArcGIS 10.1 and it works fine.

Comment: Distance: I agree about the planar verse topographic distance aspect of the results - but I believe that the fact that the planar distance measure is 15km per hour of travel times means that the error is actually larger in the topographic distance.  

Vertical Factor: If I elect to view the Toblersaway.txt in ArcGIS or ArcCatalog - it does not have two matching columns of numbers as it appears in the text file.  The none of the values align with their corresponding fields and all numbers with decimals are missing.

Comment: So, maybe the issue is a possible bug in arcgis. Did you perform a web search about that?